# How can I reduce a set of values by half while retaining one particular value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a quiz

I came up with help options:

1. call friend
2. help from public
3. fifty-fifty

I have a problem with the option fifty-fifty!

How to create an option fifty-fifty, activated with a click: it will leave 2 offered answers out of 4 available and of course one answer of the remaining 2 must be correct.

https://jsfiddle.net/e94vqfw2/

```
generateQuestion = (id_x) => {

  pitanje.innerHTML = "";
  answers.innerHTML = "";
  scoremessage.innerHTML = "";

  if (id_x === questions.length) {
    pitanje.innerHTML = "Vas rezultat je:" + score;
    document.getElementById('help1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('help2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('help3').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('error1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('error2').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('error3').style.display = "block";
    return;
  }
  var pitanja = questions[id_x];
  pitanje.innerHTML = pitanja.question;
  var correctAnswer = pitanja.answer;
  for (var i = 0; i < pitanja.answers.length; i++) {
    var answer = pitanja.answers[i];
    var odgovaranje = document.createElement('div');
    odgovaranje.setAttribute("class", "coluum");
    odgovaranje.innerHTML = answer;
    odgovaranje.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    if (answer === correctAnswer) {
      odgovaranje.addEventListener('click', nextQuestion);
    } else {
      odgovaranje.addEventListener('click', wrongAnswer);
    }
    answers.appendChild(odgovaranje);
  }
}


    halfandhalf = () => {
  if (document.getElementById('help2').onclick) {
  }
  document.getElementById('help2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('error2').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code as a [mre] in the question itself, not only at the other end of an external link. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so. Also, please explain what you've tried to do to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Also, `if (document.getElementById('help2').onclick)` just checks if the element with the id "help2" has an "onclick" attribute, which is kind of a weird thing to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have done what you pretend, here is the code that I changed:

```
halfandhalf = () => {
  if (document.getElementById('help2').onclick) {
    let answersToExclude = 2;
    while (answersToExclude > 0) {
        let indexOfAnswerToExclude = parseInt(getRandomArbitrary(0, answers.childNodes.length));
      if(answers.childNodes[indexOfAnswerToExclude].innerHTML !== questions[currentQuestion].answer) {
        answers.childNodes[indexOfAnswerToExclude].remove();
        answersToExclude--;
      }
    }

  }
  document.getElementById('help2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('error2').style.display = "block";
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Basically I get a random number between 0 and the number of answers and if it isn't the correct one I remove it. I do this two times to exclude two answers. I get a random number to exclude always random answers, and not by order.

Here is the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kh6nd5mc/1/